# IntelliJ imports Java Boolean and then throws error

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

(First of all, yes, Minecraft plugin development. Live with it)

So, I'm developing Kotlin in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, but it really hates me when it comes to importing `java.lang.Boolean` instead of `kotlin.Boolean` automagically.

My Kotlin plugin is fully up to date, and so is IntelliJ according to JB Toolbox.

Every time I press `CTRL+ALT+L` to auto-format and auto-import it imports `java.lang.Boolean` and then throws errors all over in the file that I should use `kotlin.Boolean`. Indeed, it's as simple as removing the import, but that's extra effort for nothing, as it should be able to do this itself. It may have something to do with extending a Java class, which has methods returning a Java Boolean, but I don't see how this would be the case, as it's simply way too annoying and more users should have noted it before.

If I change the return type to `java.lang.Boolean` it says the overridden class, with no connection whatsoever to Kotlin STD-Lib, uses the Kotlin version and that I should change it to `kotlin.Boolean`. This has annoyed me a while now, so do anyone have any idea?

The file in question is by the way this: https://gitlab.com/proximyst/HellishSurvival/blob/master/Plugin/src/main/java/com/proximyst/hellishsurvival/Commands.kt

Comment: Have you tried File | Invalidate Caches and restart?

Comment: Just tried, @yole, but to no luck, sadly.